# Using reddit api incorrectly?

Tags: python, api, reddit

```
import requests

def username_avail(user):
    payload = {'user': 'k9thebeast'}
    r = requests.post("https://reddit.com/api/username_availible",   data=payload)
    print(r.text)

username_avail("k9thebeast")
```

I want to check if my username is available. I keep getting a huge html page returned. I'm looking for a JSON response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try GET instead of POST.

Also try spelling `username_available` correctly ;-)

See https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_api_username_available

Comment: Thanks bro. Typos r bad